# Why isn't jQuery selector returning an object instead of an element?

Tags: jquery, select

Please help me understand why the following jquery select is returning an element rather than the expected object. Thanks.

```
<div class="partner-tab partner-tab-opaque remove4" id="tab-5"> <a href="#">
    <img class="blink" src="../skin/images/logo_endicia.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

code

```
$("<a href=\"#\" />")
    .on("click", {
    "partnerId": pid
}, function (e) {
    return showPartnerSettings(e);
})
.appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid);

// $("<a href=\"#\" />")[ < a href = ​"#" > ​ < /a> ]
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'on'

Here's the whole function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    showPartnerTabs = function (flashUSPS) {
        $.post("<?=$this->baseUrl('partner/ajaxgetactive')?>", {}, function (data) {
            var partner = data.partners;
            //alert((data.partners).length);
            /* $("#footer .partner-tab").remove();*/
            var remove = 1;
            var doc = $(document);


            for (var id in data.partners) {


                if (partner[id].toggle_value == "on") {
                    remove++;
                    logo = partner[id].logo_file;
                    var pid = parseInt(id) + 1;

                    $("<div class=\"partner-tab partner-tab-opaque remove" + remove + "\" id=\"tab-" + pid + "\" />")
                        .appendTo("#footer");

                    $("<a href=\"#\" />")
                        .on("click", {
                            "partnerId": pid
                        }, function (e) {
                            return showPartnerSettings(e);
                        })
                        .appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid);

                    var logochck = "tab-" + pid;
                    //alert(logochck);
                    if (flashUSPS && logochck == 'tab-5') {

                        $("<img class='blink' src='../skin/images/" + logo + "' />")
                            .appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid + " a");
                    } else {
                        $("<img src='../skin/images/" + logo + "' />")
                            .appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid + " a");
                    }

                    //$("</div>").appendTo("#footer");
                }

                /*
            else
            {

                $("<div class=\"partner-tab partner-tab-opaque remove" + remove + "\" id=\"tab-" + pid + "\" />")
               .appendTo("#footer");

                $("<a href=\"#\" />")
                    .on("click", { "partnerId": pid }, function(e){ return showPartnerSettings(e); })
                    .appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid);       
                $("<img src='../skin/images/" + logo + "' />")
                    .appendTo("#footer #tab-" + pid + " a");
                //$("</div>").appendTo("#footer");  
            } 
            */
            }
            //alert($(".remove2").length);
            if ($(".remove2").length > 1) {
                $($(".remove2")[0]).remove();
                $($(".remove3")[0]).remove();
                $($(".remove4")[0]).remove();
            }
        }, "json");
    }

    $(".Partnerconnection ul li .controls .toggle-switch").on("click", null, function () {
        $(this).showPartnerTabs();
    });

    showPartnerTabs(<?=$flash?>);
});
```

As I mentioned in a comment, this function worked fine until I changed the function declaration from '$.fn.showPartnerTabs()...' to 'showPartnerTabs()...'. Does this help?

Comment: What does `showPartnerSettings` do?

Comment: Which line is causing this error?  Why is the error slapped in your code like that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I tried to reformat the question so that it appears better, but it might need some more edit by the OP

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I formatted a bit better, I think.  I moved the error out of the code block.

Comment: What is `$("<a href=\"#\" />")[ < a href = ​"#" > ​ < /a>​ ]`?  I'm assuming that's what happens when you `console.log` it?

Comment: What is `{ "partnerId": pid}` supposed to do/mean in this context?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/psmb7/1/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: That sets "event data".  It can be read via `e.data.partnerId`.  Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: What does `alert($.fn.jquery)` give you? I expect to see a `TypeError $ has no property fn` which would indicate `$` is not jQuery. $() alone should never return a dom element not wrapped in a jQuery object if `$` is jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB: That's probably the issue here.  He might have not loaded jQuery, or has another library replacing `$`.

Comment: This was working fine before I changed the calling function type from jquery to javascript. I have added the function body to the original question.

Comment: `$(this).showPartnerTabs();` isn't going to work.  `$.fn.showPartnerTabs` doesn't exist.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat the error occurs on '$("<a href=\"#\" />")
                    .on("click", { "partnerId": pid }, function(e){ return showPartnerSettings(e); })'

Comment: @ChrisBarnhill: Weird.  That works fine for me.  What does `console.log($("<a href=\"#\" />"))` show?  How about `console.log($("<a href=\"#\" />") instanceof $)`?

Answer (score 5):

Because `$("<a href=\"#\" />")` is NOT a selector

You are creating a new anchor element

Other than that, your code seems to be correct. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdqJj/)

**Update**

Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'on'
```

But if you have changed `$.fn.showPartnerTabs()` to `showPartnerTabs()`, the this line

```
$(this).showPartnerTabs();
```

will throw this error

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'showPartnerTabs'
```

Please make sure the following is true

1. $ is actually jQuery and not any other library i.e.
   `console.log($("<a href=\"#\" />") instanceof $)` prints true 
    or `console.log($==jQuery)` prints true
2. You are using jQuery 1.7+ because earlier versions have no support
   for `.on`

Comment: `.on()` does work newly created elements: http://jsfiddle.net/psmb7/  The `$()` function *always* returns a jQuery object, so `has no method 'on'` should never appear.  Something else is causing that error.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new element. If you want to select:

```
<a href ="#">
```

Use an appropriate selector, in your case:

```
$('div.partner-tab a')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here and suspect you may need:

```
$("div.partner-tab").on("click", 'a', {
    "partnerId": pid
}, function (e) {
    return showPartnerSettings(e);
});
```